# PHP transforming time formats and adding random time vars

Tags: php, random, time, formatting

I need to generate a time of format : `[ Y-m-d H:i:s ]` from strings that look like `7/03/2013` ( yep, can be 7 or 07 ) .

I use

```
$date = '7/03/2013';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

This works just fine .
So where is the problem ?

The problem is that I do not have the `H:i:s` part, but I need it in order to insert to DB.

So I just tried to random it :

```
$rand = rand(00,24); 
$datenew = date('Y-m-d '.$rand.':i:s', strtotime($date));
```

but that produces time like `4` or `6` where i need `04` and `06` so :

```
$rand = rand(0,2) . rand(1,4) ;
$datenew = date('Y-m-d '.$rand.':'.$rand.':s', strtotime($date));
```

But that just seems to me  articulately non elegant .

I also need the minutes , so I need somehow to format `rand(00,60)` ;

but combining that can create also unrealistic times like `24:26:00`

So how can I take the time I have with format `7/03/2013` , transform to `H:i:s` and add random hour , minutes (and maybe sec.)

Comment: Do note that `24:00` is not valid time. Time goes from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`.

Comment: Right .. Add that to the list of problems :-) thanks,

Comment: Huh? You don't need to specify the TIME when inserting into a DATETIME   field. And even if it is, why go the long way to randomize it, when you could just insert 00:00:00?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/d/Y', '7/03/2013');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/3QF7S)

The times will vary depending on when you run the code.

Comment: that will give me always  00:00:00 . which was a bit of the original problem, how to add random HH and MM ?

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only work on newer PHP installations(after php 5.2)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Y-m-d 00:00:00` instead. Or, if you need it to be random, you could use something like:

```
date('Y-m-d ' . sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59)));
```

Comment: the 00:00:00 is created by default from my first attempt . but in order to differentiate in DB i need different times for entries created on the same date ..

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, alternatively, you could add a separate field that you increase for each record, which should differentiate them, even if they have the same time. Using a random value does not guarantee unique results.

Comment: Well, actually it is for Wordpress insert so I need the time to have different post order , but nevermind  - solution works great applied like `date('Y-m-d ' . sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59)), strtotime($date));`

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, actually I think [John Conde's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15683806/732284) is a better idea, since the time will be sequential rather than random (if sequential works for you), so you have less chance of conflict.

Comment: I looked at it . problem is that when dealing with WP , you can never know which server you end up with . and it seems like it is working only from 5.3.0. But yes, It might be better ..

Comment: I don't totally agree at this solution either. Random (better) values would not garantee an unique sequence at least not in theory.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, well, you could use his solution but with older functions. For example, you could use: `date('Y-m-d', $yourDate) . ' ' . date('H:i:s')`.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, also, consider using [`strptime()`](http://php.net/strptime) (PHP >= 5.1.0) instead of `strtotime()`, to make sure you extract the correct date from the input string.

Comment: ohh.. that function eluded me . never seen it´s existence. thanks again. learning a lot now .

Answer (score 1):

This would produce a random number for HH:ii:ss

```
$date = '7/03/2013';

$new_date  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$new_date .= date(' H:i:s', mt_rand(0,1262055681));
```