# PHP time formatting confusion

Tags: php, wordpress, time, formatting

This is actually a followup question From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683739/php-transforming-time-formats-and-adding-random-time-vars/15683806#15683806) , but it presents a whole different problem . I also know it is pretty confusing so please bear with me ,.

I have a date that presents like : `1/04/2013` which is intended to be `Jan 04 2013`

In the previous mentioned question, I had to randomly add the hours and minutes to the time format , and it works for what it was supposed to do :

```
$clr_datenew = date('Y-m-d ' . sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59)), strtotime($date));
```

this produced something like :  `2013-05-01 08:57:00`

The problem is , that now the system see that date as `MAY 1st` and not as `JAN 05`..

when I automatically insert those posts (wp) - all the posts that will have a date like `2012-05-28` will be inserted to the DB as `1970-01-01` ( I presume this is the default "wrong date" format for php .. 28th month is an error of course.. )

I tried to change the day month from

```
$clr_datenew = date('Y-m-d ' . sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59)), strtotime($date));
```

to

```
$clr_datenew = date('Y-d-m ' . sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59)), strtotime($date));
```

But it produces the same error with different date combinations .

After a colleague gave me a tip that :

> strtotime interprets x/y/z as mm/dd/yy[yy], and x-y-z as dd-mm-yyyy or
>   yy-mm-dd, depending on whether z is 4 digits or 2.

I also tried :

```
date('Y-m-d ' . sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59)), strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$clr_date)));
```

I am really loosing my mind here  :-)

I presume this is becasue I use strtotime() where the function actually "guess" how to format my time based on a loosely "human" format .

Is there a function to convert the dates from one date to another while specifying both the original date format and the wanted conversion format ??

something like `dummy_function($origformat,$wantedformat)` where I can specify `dummy_function('Y-d-m','Y-m-d')`

**EDIT I**
After reading the comment by @harke something triggered in me and combining it with the answer by @Maks3w it appears that the format which is working for me is :

```
$clr_datenew = date('Y-m-d ' . sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59)), strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$clr_date)));
```

I could not verify the Php 5.3+ methods since they are not so relevant for me as the ( internal) server in that particular company is running lower version ..

A little extra something that should be posted on every billboard of DB designers / programmers :  http://xkcd.com/1179/

That is - until further notice :-)

Comment: Have you had a look through the list of available date functions? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: @deceze - of course I have , and I also tried a lot of them, but like I said, I got a little confused by all those time format conversions .. Hence the question.

Comment: You need to specify which date format you need to use to insert the post. Only when you precisely know, you can easily write the `date()` format parameter. Right now the formatting you're creating is specified by ISO 8601 for both the first part (Calendar Date as YYYY-MM-DD) and the separated-by-space second part (Time as hh:mm:ss). However the resulting format is not an ISO 8601 valid combination of date and time which requires the letter `T` in between instead of the space. Albeit the format you use is common. However it's the wrong one as it looks like from what you write in your question.

Comment: So please clarify and specify the date-time format you need to build. Refer to some technical specification to make this more distinct. Also share the code where you assign that date to that wordpress something. Wordpress technical documentation should shed more light here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `date()` is a format mask for print literals you must escape each char with a backslash `\`

```
$clr_datenew = date('Y-m-d ' . preg_replace('/(.)/', '\\\$1', sprintf('\%d\%d\:\%d\%d\:00', mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59))), strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Thanks .. your solution actually worked on times where the DAY was smaller than `9`. on those greater than `10` it was failing again ..

Answer (score 1):

1. Decide on *one* internal time representation and stick to it. Preferably  choose one that is a *standard* across many systems. `m/d/y` is *not* such a standard (despite what many Americans like to think ;P). Virtually the universal standard is `Y-m-d H:i:s` (expressed as format string for the `date()` function). Most databases expect this format, all time related functions can parse that format without ambiguity.
2. The above is a useful *text representation* of the date that is interchangeable between different systems, but *internally* it makes sense to represent the date in an even more flexible type: a [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp) or a [`DateTime` object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). Pick one or the other and keep all your dates *internally in your code* in that format. Both allow easy *manipulation* of time values. Only change it back to a string when you need to display the date to a user or you need to send it as a string to another system (i.e. insert into a database). Don't convert back and forth between `m/d/y` strings to UNIX timestamps to `d/m/y` strings.
3. To parse a date in a known format into a UNIX timestamp or `DateTime` object to format it into something else later, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) on recent PHP versions (5.3+) or the older [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) followed by some manual reassembly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice .. as to the 1st point - the format was NOT chosen by me , I am inserting data from a 3rd party - and I am by all means NOT American. combine this with THIS and you will see the real problem. as for the 2nd and 3rd point - I do not need to represent the date, I just need to insert into DB.anyhow, it appears that my solution was more simple than predicted

Answer (score 1):

```
$date=date_format(date_create($clr_datenew), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```